# understanding COM exception

Tags: c#, office-interop

Hey I'm getting the following exception:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
Office 2010.

I've read a bunch of results and the typical solution is change debug from AnyCPU to X86.(I don't want to do this because it's a large project, but it didn't work anyway).  I want to understand the exception as well.

I was simply attempting to add a new workbook worksheet and fill it with some data, but it errs out on the creation of the Workbook due to the above exception.

```
using excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static void ExcelFunction()
    {
        excel.Workbook wb_XLS = new excel.Workbook();
        excel.Worksheet ws_XLS = new excel.Worksheet();
        ws_XLS = (excel.Worksheet)wb_XLS.ActiveSheet;
        int x, y,count;
        count = x = y = 0;
        while (x < 100)
        {
            while (y < 100)
            {
                ws_XLS.Cells[x, y] = count.ToString();
                count++;
                y++;
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It means "Class not registered".

Comment: Look in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID. Is there an entry for that guid on your machine?

Comment: More germane: did you ever install the Office Primary Interop Assemblies on your machine? They don't ship with Office by default.

Comment: Yes the entry appears to be there.

Comment: InprocServer32sub folder 14.0.0.0

Comment: @StuckOnSimpleThings - Update your question with that information. What version of Office are you using.  What line exactly throws this exception?

Comment: office 2010 and this line:  excel.Workbook wb_XLS = new excel.Workbook();

Comment: Shouldn't you first create excel application and then create a new workbook by calling Add on workbooks collection rather than calling new on excel.workbook?

Comment: Try doing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new ...` etc., then saying `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks books = app.Workbooks` before you get down to the workbook level. That is @WiktorZychla's suggestion

Comment: Are you using this from an ASP.NET project or another kind of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you first create excel application and then create a new workbook by calling Add on workbooks collection rather than calling new on excel.workbook?

```
 Excel.Application app = new ... ;
 var workbook = app.Workbooks.Add();
```